# Could we build a truth table of "$P \Rightarrow \lnot P$"? What is its meaning and its Venn Diagram?

Tags: logic

The usual truth table of $P \Rightarrow Q$ looks like this

| $P$ | $Q$ | $P \Rightarrow Q$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True |
| True | False | False |
| False | True | True |
| False | False | True |

Before determine the truth or false of $P \Rightarrow Q$.

$P \Rightarrow Q$ is like a claim.

And when we are sure that there is no way to have a condition where

$P$ is true and $Q$ is false.

Until now the claim is considered true.

Is an implication of the form $P \Rightarrow \lnot P$ valid or not valid?

What I mean by ***"valid"*** is from the quote in a book "How to prove it by D.J. Vellman".

> We will say that an argument is ***valid*** if the premises cannot all be true without the conlcusion being true ads well.

At a guess, does the truth table look like this?

| $P$ | $\lnot P$ | $P \Rightarrow \lnot P$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | False |
| False | True | True |

But what is its meaning and venn diagram?

There's a venn diagram by hand.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHfyS.jpg

[image]

Comment: You do not want a negation in front of $Q$ in the first table, right? Also, could you share what you think the Venn diagram of the first table should look like?

Comment: Oh, I should edit it. Appreciate it.

Comment: Your truth table tells us that the propositions $\neg p$ and $p\to\neg p$ are logically equivalent. In a Venn diagram it will be the complement of $p$.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim I added what I thought about the first truth table.

Comment: @drhab I did have the same idea last week, before I ask my question on this website today. But today I seem confused when I review my note.

Comment: "..does the truth table look like this?" Yes! Also the word "valid" has no meaning in propositional logic, so the question on that (valid or not) makes no sense.

Comment: ...or you must mean "valid in syntactical sense". Then the answer is: yes.

Comment: @drhab I just added the venn diagram. You may refer to it.

Comment: @drhab A sentence is often called "valid" if it is true in every model - in propositional logic, thus means true under every truth valuation of the propositional variables. Saying "$\varphi$ is valid" is just another way of saying "$\varphi$ is a tautology". This is different from what the OP says "valid" means (in the sense of a "valid argument"), but I suspect it's the intention of the question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you.

Comment: Closely related: [Can ¬p⟹p
be true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018681/basic-logic-question-can-neg-p-implies-p-be-true)

Comment: @AlexKruckman An [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232127/21813) is said to be **valid**  when the sentence $$\text{<conjunction of its premises>}\to\text{<its conclusion>}$$ is a tautology, i.e., a validity (in propositional logic, these two words are synonyms). Therefore, the OP's usage of the word ‘valid’ (in relation to arguments) ***does*** coincide with the meaning of ‘valid’ in formal logic.

Comment: @ryang I understand all that. But my interpretation of the question (possibly wrong) is that the OP was asking about the validity of $P\to \lnot P$, which is a sentence, not an argument. That's all I meant by my comment.

Comment: @AlexKruckman That too was my initial interpretation (and how I answered their question); then they subsequently edited the question to shift the reference to arguments; fortunately the distillate remains unchanged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I like to think of $P \to Q$ as a "promise" or "contract":

> I promise if $P$, then $Q$

So if I say:

> I promise if "bob dies", then "I pay \$100"

- If bob dies ($P=T$), and don't pay \$100 ($Q=F$), I've broken my promise ($F$).
- If bob dies ($P=T$), and I pay \$100 ($Q=T$), I've kept my promise ($T$).
- If bob is alive ($P=F$), and I pay \$100 ($Q=F$), I've kept my promise ($T$).

  - Just because I paid you \$100, doesn't mean bobs dead.
- If bob is alive ($P=F$), and I don't pay \$100 ($Q=F$), I've kept my promise ($T$).

##### For $\lnot P \to P$

Your statement $\lnot P \to P$ can be interpreted as:

> I promise if "I haven't paid \$100", then "I've paid \$100"

- If haven't paid \$100 ($P=F$), then I've broken the promise ($\lnot P \to P = F$).
- If I've paid \$100 ($P=T$), then I've kept the promise ($\lnot P \to P = T$)

From this we can deduce, the promise is broken only when I don't pay \$100. Or in other words it's all based on whether I've paid \$100 ($P$). Symbolically: $\lnot P \to P = P$

##### For $P \to \lnot P$

The statement $P \to \lnot P$ can be interpreted as:

> I promise if "I have paid \$100", then "I haven't paid \$100"

- If haven't paid \$100 ($P=F$), then I've kept the promise ($\lnot P \to P = T$).
- If I've paid \$100 ($P=T$), then I've broken the promise ($\lnot P \to P = F$)

From this we can deduce, the promise is broken whenever I pay \$100. So it's the opposite of before ($\lnot P$). Symbolically: $P \to \lnot P = \lnot P$

##### As a venn diagram

A useful rule to keep in mind is that: $P \to Q = \lnot P \lor Q$.

So:

- $P \to \lnot P = \lnot P \lor \lnot P = \lnot P$
- $\lnot P \to P = \lnot \lnot P \lor P = P$

As a venn diagram this view also helps since: $\lnot P$ can be seen as "everything that's not in P".

And $\lor$ can be interpreted as combining the [two venn-diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nvbn.png).

So your statement: $P \to \lnot P = \lnot P \lor \lnot P$, illustrated here:
[image: venn diagram for P implies not P]

Which you can see at the end just equals $\lnot P$.

For your other one: $\lnot P \to P = \lnot \lnot P \lor P = P \lor P$, illustrated here:
[image: venn diagram for not P implies P]

Which ends up as just $P$.

(I've written $u$ as the universe in the image out of habit, which you seem to have used $d$ instead, presumably as the domain of discourse which is also correct.)

##### Validity of $P \to \lnot P$

Usually when we talk about an argument being valid, we have a set of premises: {"Socrates is a man", "All men are mortal"}, and a conclusion "Socrates is mortal".

Symbolically: $(\text{"Socrates is a man"} \land \text{"All men are mortal"}) \to \text{"Socrates is mortal"}$

An equivalent definition of validity is:

> An argument is valid if and only if it would be contradictory for the conclusion to be false if all of the premises are true

Here the premises is the set: {"Socrates is a man", "All men are mortal"}, and we ask:

> Would it be contradictory for "Socrates is mortal" to be false if "Socrates is a man" and "All men are mortal" are both true?
> Yes! Therefore it is valid.

If your asking if $P \to \lnot P$ is valid, we'll take the premises as the set $\{ P \}$, and we ask:

> Would it be contradictory for $\lnot P$ to be false if $P$ was true?
> No. This it is not contradictory, rather very natural.

So the statement $P \to \lnot P$ invalid.

In propositional logic, these valid arguments are tautologies, basically statements which are always true. As you can see $P \to \lnot P$ is not always true.

Comment: Your username does not check out

Answer (score 2):

> $P \Rightarrow Q$ is like a claim.

Conventions vary, but some (many?) authors read $$P \Rightarrow Q$$ as a *metalogical assertion* that the logical operation (or truth function) $$P \to Q$$ is *true* (which means that either $P$ is false or $Q$ is true).

($P$ and $Q$ and $P \to Q$ and $P \Rightarrow Q$ are all sentences.)

> | $P$ | $\lnot P$ | $P \Rightarrow \lnot P$ |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | True | False | False |
> | False | True | True |
>
> Is an implication of the form $P \Rightarrow \lnot P$ valid or not valid?

The third column of the above truth table shows that the sentence $$P \to \lnot P$$ is a **contingency**, i.e., a sentence that is neither a **tautology** nor a **contradiction**. In propositional (though not in first-order) logic, **tautology** and **validity** are synonyms; so, the sentence is certainly not a validity.

Based on the above convention (where we read $\Rightarrow$ as asserting that $\to$ *is* true), the implication $$P \Rightarrow \lnot P$$ is therefore actually asserting that sentence $P$ is false.

> But what is its meaning and venn diagram?

Since Venn diagrams deal with sets of objects, I'd rewrite $$P \Rightarrow \lnot P$$ as $$\forall x\;\big(P(x) \Rightarrow \lnot P(x)\big),$$ which is illustrated as a sunny-side-up where the yolk represents $P(x)$ and the entire egg represents $\lnot P(x).$ However, $P(x)$ and $\lnot P(x)$ are disjoint, so have an empty intersection. Therefore, $P(x)$ is actually the empty set, i.e., $P(x)$ is true for no $x,$ i.e., $P$ is false. This conclusion is consistent with that in the previous paragraph.

Summarising: $$P \to \lnot P\quad \equiv\quad \lnot P.$$

Comment: It seems hard to understand. But I am curious still.

Comment: @StatsCruncher If you need any clarification, please feel free to ask. To me, $P{\implies}\lnot P$ is just an indirect way to mean that proposition $P$ is false. $\forall x\;\big(A(x) \Rightarrow \lnot B(x)\big)$ is illustrated as circle $A$ (i.e., the set of objects satisfying $A(x)\,)$ lying within circle $B,$ i.e., set $A$ being a subset of set $B.$

Comment: @StatsCruncher In case you wonder why noob's Venn diagram differs from mine, theirs is illustrating $\lnot P,$ which is an algebraic simplification of $P{\implies}\lnot P,$ while I am attempting to interpret a direct illustration of $P{\implies}\lnot P.$

Comment: @StatsCruncher [An argument of the form Premises$\Rightarrow$Conclusion being **valid** means that $P\to C$ is validity (i.e., tautology).](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4232127/21813)

Comment: How do you know these things to explain knowledge on logic and proof? There are so many different terminologies used in your and other users' anwsers. Would you like to recommend textbooks on logic and proof? Or onlice coureses?

Comment: @StatsCruncher Indeed, I frequently disclaim this in my answers here: “symbolic logic is an area rife with conflicting notation, terminology and even notions; my understanding is eclectically evolving.” [This](https://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf) is very accessible read, and [this](https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl/) is excellent ([the author](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/35151/peter-smith)); both are free to download. What different terminologies are you referring to? As I said before, if you need any clarification, feel free to ask!

Comment: I happened to know the same book of Prof. Peter Smith yesterday before I left my comment to you about textbooks. Currently I consider another book "How to prove it by Prof. Velleman" as my primary source to boost my confidence in writing proofs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how useful a Venn diagram would be here, but if $P$ is true implies $P$ is false, then $P$ must be false.

Symbolically: $(P\implies \neg P)\implies \neg P$.

Here is the truth table:

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

Here is a formal proof by contradiction using a form of natural deduction (screenshot from my proof checker):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach it via the adjunction
$$R\to (S\to W)\ \ \iff\ \ (R\land S)\to W$$

Examples:

"**If** it's a rainy day, **then if** I'm also out on the street, **then** I'm gonna be wet."

"**If** it's a rainy day **and** I'm also out on the street, **then** I'm gonna be wet."

---

Now you can read $\neg P$ as $P\to \bot$ where $\bot$ denotes any false claim. To say $P$ is false is to say that it implies something absurd. With this,

$$P\to \neg P\ \ \iff\ \ P\to (P\to\bot)\ \ \iff\ \ (P\land P)\to \bot\ \ \iff\ \ \neg (P\land P)\iff\ \ \neg P$$

So $P\to \neg P$ is a weird way of saying $P$ is false, just like $\neg (P\land P)$ would be a weird way of saying it.

You could just tell your friend ($\neg P$)

"I would **not** enjoy having to wake up so early tomorrow."

Where I translate "$P$" to a the waking up task and the negation "$\bullet\to\bot$" to non-enjoyment.

But you could also tell your friend, along the lines of the latter variant ($\neg (P\land P)$)

"I would **not** enjoy, both having to wake up so early tomorrow **and** having to wake up so early tomorrow."

but the second is redundant from a classical logic perspective. Indeed so redundant that it would be weird to even say it.

Roughly framing would be along the lines of ($P\to \neg P$)

"**If** I would have to wake up so early tomorrow, **then** I would **not** enjoy *it* (having to wake up so early tomorrow)."

Indeed the semantics of $P\to (P\to Q)$ is that of $P\to Q$ for the same reason.

Answer (score -3):

P ⇒ ¬P is a contradiction and therefore it's invalid. I mean, if P is true then P is... not true? But we just said P is true. That doesn't work and therefore a truth table can't be constructed.

Comment: The proposition $p\to\neg p$ is true if $p$ is false, so it is not a contradiction. Also truth tables can *always* be constructed in propositional logic.

Comment: @GMoss Don't you think a contradiction should occur in a situation such as P^¬P other than P ⇒ ¬P?

Comment: @StatsCruncher A contradiction is a formula that is false for *every* valuation. An example is $p\wedge\neg p$ but certainly not $p\to\neg p$.

Comment: @drhab Yes, you're correct. This is what I get for answering after years of not taking logic.